# How to find specific digit in integer in Python?

Tags: python

I need to write function which can check if there is a specific digit in some entered number.

```
def number(m):

    while (m>0):
        n=m%10
        m = m/100

        if n==2:
           return True         
     return False

some_number = 223
number(some_number)
```

For example I'm searching for number 2. But with this code it returns True only if number 2 is on last place.
Thanks.

Comment: one (admittedly not too performant) approach would just be to convert the number to a string using `str(m)` and then searching that string for the digit (using standard library functions or your own)

Comment: Probably more performant than the arithmetic approach still.

Comment: You should try `regex`. Your case is simple but regex will help you even hard to check complex pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. Why do steps of `100`? Do instead steps of `10` using `floor division` , otherwise you'll miss some algorisms and your loop will be waaay deeper than it should (for example, for the number `123`, your loop as of now would check 12.3, 1.23, 0.123, 0.0123, 0.00123...... until it is so small that its computationally 0 - You don't want that, because you'd just be adding more and more zeros to your `m` and a `2` would never show up anyway).

```
def number(m):

    while (m>0):
        n = m%10
        m = m//10

        if n==2:
            return True         
    return False
```

Checking

```
>> print(number(1))
False
>> print(number(2))
True
>> print(number(13))
False
>> print(number(12))
True
>> print(number(21))
True
>> print(number(11))
False
>> print(number(121))
True
```

Comment: I really don't know why I put there 100 instead of 10. God xD Thank you so much. It works!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: use `divmod` to get result & remainder at the same time

Answer (score 2):

You should divide by 10 instead of 100 in your code.

Also as Tilman B. aka Nerdyyy mention, you can just convert the integer to str, and search using `in` opearator:

```
def number(m):
    return '2' in str(m)
```

Comment: Or you can search like(probably not the best solution) this: `1 in list(map(lambda x: int(x), list(str(1234))))`

Comment: @FUNNYDMAN the only thing I'd say is that that isn't all that readable. `"2" in str(m)` is, in my opinion, easier to understand.

Comment: `lambda x: int(x)` is `int` actually

Comment: Nice catch! Thanks. Also just because of curiosity I've checked speed of this two one. `"2" in str(m)` works much faster. It was expected.